# What does Apple mean by "No cancellation of the current subscription is allowed during active subscription period."?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am building an iOS-app that features in-app auto-renewal subscriptions. It has been rejected by the app store with the following requirement not met:

You have to disclose the following information to the user:

- No cancellation of the current subscription is allowed during active subscription period.

To me that text says that a user cannot cancel an active subscription. That can't be right? A user can cancel an auto-renewed subscription any time, and then the next period will not auto-renew right? I have to disclose that information in my native language, but i don't understand what it means.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple subscription policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the word 'month' instead of 'period' for easier understanding:

The user cannot cancel the current month in the middle of a month. So if your subscription costs $3/month, the user cannot cancel mid-month and expect to get $1.50 back.  The cancellation will take effect next month.